# Entity Framework Core "One (or Many?) to Many" relationship on one Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

What I am trying to achieve is pretty easy with Plain SQL. But with Entity Framework it feels like something complex. I have found some questions/pages with a similar question, but most of them are 6-8 years old and do not reflect the current Entity Framework Core syntax.

For example this page seems to reflect what I am trying to achieve: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/276/entity-framework-recipe-many-to-many-relationship-on-the-same-table

In my application I am using `Permissions`. These permissions are really specific. An example is `ProfileView`. If a user wants to view a user profile, the user should also have the permissions `ProfileGet` and `RoleGet`.
The UI will automatically select the checkbox of `ProfileGet` and `RoleGet` when someone checks `ProfileView`.

So when returning the Permissions API result, I want to also include the Permissions it relates to. For example:

```
{
  "PermissionId": 1,
  "Name": "ProfileView",
  "RelatedPermissions": [
    {
      "PermissionId": 2,
      "Name": "ProfileGet "
    },
    {
      "PermissionId": 3,
      "Name": "RoleGet"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am at the point that the `PermissionRelation` table is created, and seems to be filled correctly:
[image]

But when adding the 31 permissions with their related permissions, I end up with 98 records in the `Permissions` table. So I end up with doubles, and I cannot get my mind to fix this (perhaps) simple issue.

The entities are defined like this:

```
public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PermissionRelation> RelatedPermissions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PermissionRelation> RelatedPermissionsTo { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionRelation
{
    public int PermissionRelationId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Parent { get; set; }

    public int? ChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Child { get; set; }
}
```

The `DbContext` is defined like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionRelation>()
            .HasOne(permissionRelation => permissionRelation.Parent)
            .WithMany(permission => permission.RelatedPermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(relation => relation.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionRelation>()
            .HasOne(permissionRelation => permissionRelation.Child)
            .WithMany(permission => permission.RelatedPermissionsTo)
            .HasForeignKey(relation => relation.ChildId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

I am inserting the permissions with the following code **(updated to a working situation)**:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> permissions = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"ProfileView", new List<string>()
    {
        "ProfileGet",
        "RoleGet"
    }},
    {"ProfileGet", new List<string>()
    {
        "RoleGet"
    }}
    // Removed other permissions for readability
};

await using IDbContextTransaction transaction = await _databaseContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

await using IDbContextTransaction transaction = await _databaseContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

try
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> permissionToAdd in permissions)
    {
        await _databaseContext.Permissions.AddAsync(new Permission
        {
            Name = permissionToAdd.Key
        });
    }

    await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> permissionToAdd in permissions)
    {
        Permission? permission =
            await _databaseContext.Permissions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(permission =>
                permission.Name == permissionToAdd.Key);

        if (permission != null)
        {
            List<PermissionRelation> relatedPermissions = new List<PermissionRelation>();
            foreach (string relatedPermissionToAdd in permissionToAdd.Value)
            {
                Permission? relatedPermission =
                    await _databaseContext.Permissions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(relatedPermission =>
                        relatedPermission.Name == relatedPermissionToAdd);

                if (relatedPermission != null)
                {
                    relatedPermissions.Add(new PermissionRelation()
                    {
                        Parent = permission,
                        Child = relatedPermission
                    });
                }
            }

            permission.RelatedPermissions = relatedPermissions;

            _databaseContext.Permissions.Update(permission);
        }
    }

    await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
```

The relations table is now correctly filled and I have the correct amount of rows in the `Permissions` table.
But when trying to read the `Permissions` including their related Permissions like this:

```
List<Permission> permissions =
    _databaseContext.Permissions
        .Include(permission => permission.RelatedPermissions)
        .ThenInclude(relation => relation.Child)
        .ToList();
```

Results in the following exception:

```
JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.RelatedPermissions.Parent.PermissionId.
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is inserting the values into the table using EF?

Comment: @floating_camel sure thing, I have edited the question above. When you asked this I started thinking that I maybe expect too much magic from Entity Framework.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty clear that I am inserting it the wrong way. I marked the Name field on the entity as Unique, and now it actually tells me there are duplicate keys when importing the Permissions.

I guess I will first need to import all the base Permissions, and then update the `RelatedPermissions` using the `Ids` later.

Comment: I updated the question again. I am now able to import the `Permissions` correctly, but I now have problems receiving them again.

Also I think to resulting solution is unnecessarily complex. I hope someone can bump me in the right direction on how to solve this the most correct way.

Comment: You have a recursive structure parent - child relationship which an linq is not meant to query results.  Try getting parent ID in one query than look up child id in second query.  You query is getting parent - child and all descendants which creates a loop,

Comment: You are using a so-called "adjacency list". Search by this term.

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with Entity Framework. It is thrown out by the json serializer. See [Preserving Object References](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preserveobjectreferences.htm), [How to preserve references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Eventually I ditched this design choice, to save time.

I am now only going to have a Many-to-Many relation between the `Permissions` and the `Roles`. Selecting the right related/required permissions is now a task for the user.